# Derivative under an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am being asked to find a formula for: (Side note: generally we consider $I$ compact)

$\frac{d}{dt}\Big[\int_{t_0}^{t}f(t,s)ds\Big]$, $t\in I$

Here $f\in C^1(I\hspace{1mm}\text{x}\hspace{1mm}I)$ and $t_0\in I$

Hint is to use the definition of the derivative.

I am wondering if someone can help me understand the given information and how it is relevant

$\textbf{My attempt}$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big[\int_{t_0}^{t}f(t,s)ds\Big]\stackrel{Leibniz}{=}f(t,t)*1-f(t,t_0)*0+\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{d}{dt}f(t,s)ds$$

$$=f(t,t)+\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{d}{dt}f(t,s)ds$$

I am not so sure what to do with the integral from here (if this is correct) or if the other information is needed some how

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I would ask that you write partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s,t)$ in your integral, but otherwise this is correct. Is the point that you're supposed to *prove* this? That's not hard, but nor is it easy.

Comment: I believe the first term in the first line should read $"f(t,t)*1 - ..."$ so the last line should have the first term as $f(t,t)$.

Comment: Thank you, I have made edits. @TedShifrin What do you mean to "prove?" Also, why write it with the $s,t$ switched?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the function H(x,y ) = I[t_0,x]f(y,s)ds]  and put x=t and y=t ;You are interested in d/dt H (t,t) = partial/dx H (x,y)at x=t,y=t * dx/dt + 
partial/dy H(x,y)at x=t,y=t *dy/dt   = f(t,t) +I[t_0,t] d/dy f(y,s)at y=t ds .

Now note that d/dy f(y,s) at y=t is usually written partial/dt f(t ,s) so tha final answer is f(t,t) + I[t_0 ,t] partial/dt f(t,s)ds .

I[t_0,t] is of course integral from t_0 to t .You had it exactly right . Also t_o is constant through out ,no need to take derivative with respect to t_0 
And I see You  had the right method .This problem is a notatonal nightmare ,isn't it . It is important though .Regards Stuart M.N.